# How Java fx user inputs insert to the database

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I have made a form for users to enter details and I want to insert those data to the database. Here is the relavent codes, But this is not working. can someone point out what are the errors which I made here.

```
   @FXML
    private TextField name,id,docter,phone,time;
    @FXML
    private TextArea covid;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker date;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    int rs;

    @FXML
    private void newappoinment() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        //Database connection
        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/medibase";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "0852";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL,username,password);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //
        String Pname=name.getText();
        String Pid=id.getText();
        String docname=docter.getText();
        Integer phoneno=phone.getColumns();
        String atime=time.getText();
        String covidnote=covid.getText();
        String appdate=date.getPromptText();
        pst=connection.prepareStatement("Insert INTO appoinment (Patient_Name," +
                "Patient_ID,Docter_Name,Patient_Phone,App_Date,Covid_Note,App_time)VALUES " +
                "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(1,Pname);
        pst.setString(2,Pid);
        pst.setString(3,docname);
        pst.setInt(4,phoneno);
        pst.setString(5,atime);
        pst.setString(6,covidnote);
        pst.setString(7,appdate);
        rs= pst.executeUpdate();
```

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.DashController.newappoinment(DashController.java:73)
    ... 58 more
```

currently im getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException , I think there are more than one mistake coz im new to java

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace. An `InvocationTargetException` is virtually never the root cause and basically tells us nothing exception "a method invoked via reflection threw an exception". So you (and we) need to look at the `Caused by:` in the stack trace.

Comment: Which is line 73?

Comment: Is `docter` a typo ?

Comment: How can we help if we don't even know the right amount of columns, column names and order in your mySQL database? Furthermore, looks like you got a nullpointerexception as well, could be as lame as a null string from your form. In other words, we need a lot more info in order to help...